# Anyone help give a counterexample when $\inf_{x∈X}⁡(\sup_{y∈Y}⁡F(x,y) )\le \sup_{y∈Y}⁡(\inf_{x∈X}⁡F(x,y) )$ is false

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F(x,y)$ be a $X\times Y \to \Bbb R$ function and $X,Y$ are subsets in $\Bbb R^n$, anyone help give a counterexample when $\inf_{x∈X}⁡(\sup_{y∈Y}⁡F(x,y) )\le \sup_{y∈Y}⁡(\inf_{x∈X}⁡F(x,y) )$ is false?

---

PS: The other direction is true because

> [image]

Comment: for all $x_0,y_0$ it holds that $F(x_0,y_0)\geq\inf_{x}F(x,y_0)$. hence the inequality also holds for the supremum: for all $x_0$ you have $\sup_{y} F(x_0,y)\geq\sup_{y} \inf_{x}F(x,y)$. again, since this inequality holds for all $x_0$ it also holds for the infumum: $\inf_{x}\sup_{y} F(x,y)\geq\sup_{y} \inf_{x}F(x,y)$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. : this is not a duplicate of what you linked. it might be a duplicate of something else since it is basic, but your flag is false.

Comment: @Max How is it not duplicate? They ask the same thing.

Comment: i must admit i didnt read the full question before commenting. shame on me xD

Comment: Very sorry. My bad. I misunderstood the question myself.